# GridGain wont load partitioned

Tags: java, gridgain

~/.bashrc setting

- export GRIDGAIN_HOME=~/Downloads/gridgain-platform-os-6.1.9-nix

I cannot get the server to load the partitioned config as it keep throwing errors from java;

- Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cache is not configured: partitioned

The command line admin console gives the following:

```
ADMIN CONSOLE
 2014 Copyright (C) GridGain Systems

+-----------------------------------------+
| Status      | Connected                 |
| Grid name   | <default>                 |
| Config path | config/default-config.xml |
| Uptime      | 00:00:00                  |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

This is the command I use to start the app;

I have also tried

- {GRIDGAIN_HOME}/bin/ggstart.{bat|sh} examples/config/example-cache.xml

as suggested in the documentation also.

```
[aaa@sandbox bin]$ ./ggstart.sh ../config/default-config.xml
[16:06:56]   _____     _     _______      _         
[16:06:56]  / ___/____(_)___/ / ___/___ _(_)___     
[16:06:56] / (_ // __/ // _  / (_ // _ `/ // _ \   
[16:06:56] \___//_/ /_/ \_,_/\___/ \_,_/_//_//_/
[16:06:56]  
[16:06:56] ver. 6.1.9-os#20140627-sha1:88a243e1
[16:06:56] 2014 Copyright (C) GridGain Systems
[16:06:56] 
[16:06:56] Quiet mode.
[16:06:56]   ^-- Logging to file '/home/aaa/Downloads/gridgain-platform-os-6.1.9-nix/work/log/gridgain-95b42fea.%g.log'
[16:06:56]   ^-- To see **FULL** console log here add -DGRIDGAIN_QUIET=false or "-v" to ggstart.{sh|bat}
[16:06:56] 
[16:06:57] Failed to create Protobuf marshaller for REST C++ and .NET clients (consider adding gridgain-protobuf module to classpath).
[16:06:57] Failed to initialize HTTP REST protocol (consider adding gridgain-rest-http module to classpath).
[16:06:59] New version is available at www.gridgain.org: 6.2.0-rc5
[16:06:59] If running benchmarks, see http://bit.ly/GridGain-Benchmarking
[16:06:59] To start Console Management & Monitoring run ggvisorcmd.{sh|bat}
[16:06:59] 
[16:06:59] GridGain node started OK (id=95b42fea)
[16:06:59] Topology snapshot [ver=1, nodes=1, CPUs=4, heap=1.0GB]
```

And as soon as I call this;

These are the different ways I tried to start the grid form java.

- grid = GridGain.start("/home/aaa/Downloads/gridgain-platform-os-6.1.9-nix/config/default-config.xml");
- grid = GridGain.start("/home/aaa/Downloads/gridgain-platform-os-6.1.9-nix/config/example-cache.xml");
- grid = GridGain.start("/config/default-config.xml");
- grid = GridGain.start("/config/example-cache.xml");
- grid = GridGain.start();
- final GridCache cache = grid.cache("partitioned");

it blows up and does this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cache is not configured: partitioned
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.publicCache(GridCacheProcessor.java:1697)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridKernal.cache(GridKernal.java:2782)
    at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(xxx.java:296)
    at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(xxx.java:124)
    at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.main(xxx.java:542)
```

and I also get this;

```
Initializing settings
Reading sites:
Site file read!
Exception in thread "main" class org.gridgain.grid.GridException: Failed to create GridGain component (consider adding gridgain-spring module to classpath) [component=SPRING, cls=org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.spring.GridSpringProcessorImpl]
For more information see:
    Troubleshooting:      http://bit.ly/GridGain-Troubleshooting
    Documentation Center: http://bit.ly/GridGain-Documentation

    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridComponentType.componentException(GridComponentType.java:239)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridComponentType.create0(GridComponentType.java:230)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridComponentType.create(GridComponentType.java:141)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx.loadConfigurations(GridGainEx.java:509)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx.start(GridGainEx.java:687)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx.start(GridGainEx.java:626)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx.start(GridGainEx.java:491)
    at org.gridgain.grid.GridGain.start(GridGain.java:314)
    at com.tupl.geolocation.GeolocationComputation.<init>(GeolocationComputation.java:95)
    at com.tupl.geolocation.GeolocationComputation.main(GeolocationComputation.java:542)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:       org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.spring.GridSpringProcessorImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridComponentType.create0(GridComponentType.java:216)
    ... 8 more
```

What am I missing?

Kind Regards...

Comment: "partitioned" is the name of the cache which must be specified in configuration. Most likely you don't have cache with such name configured. Please take a look at data grid examples shipped with the product. If you still cannot get it to work, please provide code for how you start GridGain here.

Comment: Hello and thank you fro your comment.  Actually the partitioned name is in the config file, first section.  I also followed the directly exactly as they were.  The code is above on how I start the grid for both the java code and the command line for the node.

Comment: I don't see a call to `GridGain.start("path/to/config/file")` anywhere above. Are you starting a grid node before using it? Again, many examples for it in the examples folder.

Comment: Thank you again and I just updated with the code I have in java with more error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get rid of the error above by adding spring via maven.  I must have missed that.  But now I can only open the default config.  If I try to use the "examples/config/example-cache.xml"

Works:

- grid = GridGain.start("/config/default-config.xml");

Throws another error:

- grid = GridGain.start("/config/example-cache.xml");

  Exception in thread "main" class org.gridgain.grid.GridException: Failed to instantiate Spring XML
  application context 
  [springUrl=file:/home/aaa/Downloads/gridgain-platform-os-6.1.9-nix/examples/config/example-cache.xml,
  err=Error creating bean with name 'grid.cfg' defined in URL 
  [file:/home/aaa/Downloads/gridgain-platform-os-6.1.9-nix/examples/config/example-cache.xml]: 
  Cannot create inner bean 'org.gridgain.grid.spi.indexing.h2.GridH2IndexingSpi#17fd8d42' of type
  [org.gridgain.grid.spi.indexing.h2.GridH2IndexingSpi] while setting bean property 'indexingSpi' 
  with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException:
  Cannot find class [org.gridgain.grid.spi.indexing.h2.GridH2IndexingSpi] for bean with name 
  'org.gridgain.grid.spi.indexing.h2.GridH2IndexingSpi#17fd8d42' defined in URL 
  [file:/home/aaa/Downloads/gridgain-platform-os-6.1.9-nix/examples/config/example-cache.xml]; 
  nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  org.gridgain.grid.spi.indexing.h2.GridH2IndexingSpi]

  For more information see:
      Troubleshooting:      http://bit.ly/GridGain-Troubleshooting
      Documentation Center: http://bit.ly/GridGain-Documentation

I have no idea what this one means.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `grid = GridGain.start("examples/config/example-cache.xml")`. Example configuration is located in `examples` folder under root.

Comment: Sorry, above is a typo, I did try that. When ever I try this examples/config/example-cache.xml from the command line it also just hangs. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you change any configuration or are you using everything provided out of the box? If nothing changed, then make sure that you don't have any other zombie grid node running. If you changed configuration, then please provide it here (you can use http://pastebin.com to paste code).

Comment: I didnt change anything, everything is out of the box.  Also, no other grid is running.  Really stumped on this one.

Comment: Try the latest 6.2.0 release, there were some changes in marshalling protocol that may have fixed it for you.

Comment: Thank you Dmitriy, downloading now.